# Multiple versions of the same package in the yarn.lock file

Tags: javascript, webpack, yarnpkg

I see 3 different version of one package in the yarn.lock, for example:

```
angular@1.6:
  version "1.6.10"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/angular/-/angular-1.6.10.tgz#eed3080a34d29d0f681ff119b18ce294e3f74826"
  integrity sha512-PCZ5/hVdvPQiYyH0VwsPjrErPHRcITnaXxhksceOXgtJeesKHLA7KDu4X/yvcAi+1zdGgGF+9pDxkJvghXI9Wg==

angular@>=1.4.0, angular@^1.0.8:
  version "1.7.7"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/angular/-/angular-1.7.7.tgz#26bd87693deadcbd5944610a7a0463fc79a18803"
  integrity sha512-MH3JEGd8y/EkNCKJ8EV6Ch0j9X0rZTta/QVIDpBWaIdfh85/e5KO8+ZKgvWIb02MQuiS20pDFmMFlv4ZaLcLWg==

angular@~1.2.0:
  version "1.2.32"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/angular/-/angular-1.2.32.tgz#df52625a5167919931418dda3a9208b9f5fa3db4"
  integrity sha1-31JiWlFnkZkxQY3aOpIIufX6PbQ=
```

Does that mean the final bundle contains all of them, otherwise how webpack knows which version to select? What is the best practice in the community to deal with that? I know about `--flat` option but there are thousands packages, it would take a while for me to select one for each.

Comment: Here is an explanation article about `yarn.lock` duplicates (https://medium.com/@scinos/de-duplicating-yarn-lock-ae30be4aa41a) and a tool which may help to fix this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-deduplicate

Comment: @Andriy it does nothing for some reason, it says version is 1.1.1, but on github 1.0.0 is the last available, strange.

Comment: I did not check it on my npm packages, just gave you some theory. If you still need help, let me know and I will try to help (by playing with yarn locally :))

Answer (score 13):

To investigate how many times a depenedency is installed and what packages dependens on it (recursivly), run: `yarn why <package-name>`.

See if you can upgrade (or downgrade) some packages to ensure that all of the dependencies in your package are using the same version of angular.

For example: `yarn why execa`:

```
yarn why v1.22.5
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "execa"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
[4/4]   Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "execa@4.0.3"
info Has been hoisted to "execa"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "workspace-aggregator-c3b3be41-6d00-4635-98a6-d5373b215152" depends on it
   - Specified in "devDependencies"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#pretty-quick#execa"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#@tahini#nc#execa"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#execa"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest#@jest#core#jest-changed-files#execa"
info Disk size without dependencies: "136KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "520KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "736KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 19
=> Found "lint-staged#execa@2.1.0"
info This module exists because "_project_#lint-staged" depends on it.
info Disk size without dependencies: "76KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "400KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "616KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 19
=> Found "sane#execa@1.0.0"
info This module exists because "_project_#jest-haste-map#sane" depends on it.
info Disk size without dependencies: "40KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "328KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "524KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 16
=> Found "create-folder-structure#execa@2.1.0"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "_project_#create-folder-structure#pretty-quick" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "_project_#create-folder-structure#pretty-quick#execa"
info Disk size without dependencies: "76KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "400KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "616KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 19
=> Found "term-size#execa@0.7.0"
info This module exists because "_project_#nodemon#update-notifier#boxen#term-size" depends on it.
info Disk size without dependencies: "36KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "324KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "520KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 16
```

Note:

- Sometimes a dev-dependency is causing that.

Answer (score 10):

As another answer mentioned, these extra versions can be due to dev dependencies and may not actually end up in your shipped JS bundle.  I'd recommend using a bundle analyzer to ensure that your app only ships with a single version of all large modules like angular.

Another thing to note is that yarn v1.x does not aggressively optimize and de-duplicate module versions.  If you want the smallest number of packages in your yarn.lock file, you'll want to execute the utility npm module `yarn-deduplicate` immediately after adding or upgrading yarn packages, ie:

```sh
npm install -g yarn-deduplicate
yarn-deduplicate yarn.lock
```

This utility will analyze and optimize the yarn.lock file so that all version dependencies are satisfied with a minimal set of modules.  In your example above, running `yarn-deduplicate yarn.lock` would likely consolidate the first 2 angular versions in your yarn.lock into a single version:

```
angular@>=1.4.0, angular@^1.0.8, angular@1.6:
  version "1.6.10"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/angular/-/angular-1.6.10.tgz#eed3080a34d29d0f681ff119b18ce294e3f74826"
  integrity sha512-PCZ5/hVdvPQiYyH0VwsPjrErPHRcITnaXxhksceOXgtJeesKHLA7KDu4X/yvcAi+1zdGgGF+9pDxkJvghXI9Wg==
```

This optimization/de-duplication is built into yarn v2.x, so I'd recommend upgrading yarn so that you do not have to worry about this issue going forward with your project.

Comment: The command to de-duplicate in yarn v2.x is `yarn dedupe` ✌️